# is there any way of not using array list in my contact book java

Tags: java

is there any other way instead of using array list? in my assignment we are not allowed to use an array list, array is fine but not an array list at all ....basically it is a contact list book that saves 20 contacts.  every contact has to be shown in alphabetical way.

main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Contact> lsCont = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    Contact[] contacts = new Contact[20];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String phone;
    String email;
    int maxContacts = 20;

    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("insert first name : ");
        firstName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("insert last Name : ");
        lastName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("insert phone : ");
        phone = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("insert email : ");
        email = scanner.nextLine();

        Contact cont = new Contact(firstName, lastName, phone, email);

        lsCont.add(cont);

        Collections.sort(lsCont);

        for (Contact contact : lsCont) {
            System.out.println(contact.toString());

        }
        if (i == maxContacts) {
            System.out.println("maxiumum number of adding contact has reached");
            break;
            }
         }

     }
 }
```

Contact

```
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact> {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String phone;
private String email;

public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String phone, String email) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Contact obj) {
    return this.lastName.compareTo(obj.lastName);

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Contacts:  firstName = " + firstName + ", lastName = " + lastName + ", phone = " + phone + ", email = " + email;
   }

}
```

Comment: The "other" way is the way you seem to be (trying) to do it, using `Contact[] contacts = new Contact[20];` Your instructor wants you to come up with ways of inserting, deleting, sorting and fetching data. So what seems to be the problem?

Comment: we cant use array list, but i dont think there is any other option

Comment: You already started to add code to use an array, so how is that not an option?

Comment: you can use array but not array list

Comment: Pedantically, `LinkedList` will produce the same behavior as `ArrayList` in this instance but is not an ArrayList. The other logical option is to use an array. Another option your teacher will hate is using a `Map`, which is also not an ArrayList but also a terrible solution to the core problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size of `Contact` array then you can just go with array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int maxContacts = 20;
    Contact[] contacts = new Contact[maxContacts];    // initialize array of size 20
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String phone;
    String email;

   //collect 20 contacts into array
    for (int i = 0; i < maxContacts; i++) {

         System.out.println("insert first name : ");
         firstName = scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.println("insert last Name : ");
         lastName = scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.println("insert phone : ");
         phone = scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.println("insert email : ");
         email = scanner.nextLine();

         contacts[i] = new Contact(firstName, lastName, phone, email);
    }

   // Just print contacts array is full
    if (contacts.length == maxContacts) {
        System.out.println("maxiumum number of adding contact has reached");
        }

      //Now just sort the array based on name
      Arrays.sort(contacts);

     //Finally print contacts in order
     for (Contact contact : contacts) {
        System.out.println(contact.toString());

    }

 }
```

Comment: everything looks good but after each entry how can i println of the old entry and the new one

Comment: I will only tell how to do that but you have to find out by googling, after collecting contacts into array then make a copy of that before sorting @attash